# Mangeto2 create custom product attributes in different languages

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, language

What is the right approach to create a custom required attribute to a product like "Volume" in English and  "Volym" in Swedish. The attribute has to be required and the product will be used not only in different Store Views, but also in Different Web Stores ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento (including 2) is built such that translation is closely tied to store views. Each store view has a language defined.

If you want to use translation across multiple websites, you'll need a store view per language within each one. (Website A, store views English and Swedish; Website B, store views English and Swedish; ...)

At that point, when creating or editing an attribute, you will be able to translate the label and options for each store view separately. You can also translate product text values (name, description, etc.) by changing the store view scope while editing the product. There's a dropdown for that at the top left of the form.